# Why to upgrade React on upgrading Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to upgrade Material UI from version V0 to V4. I am using react version 15. Do I need to upgrade React also? Why?

Comment: Read the upgrade dosc or release docs of material ui. If it needs react dependency over certain version then you need to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material-ui V4 is using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). It was added in react 16.8:

> Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and
>   other React features without writing a class.

So when migrating to material-ui v4, you must upgrade react to version > 16.8, 
because material-ui v4 relies on hooks.

You can refer to the migration docs:

1. [Migration to v1](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/)
2. [V3 release docs](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v3.0.0)
3. [Migration to v4](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/)